# Why do I get two different values in heatmap and feature_importances?

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, heatmap

I'm running a feature selection using sns.heatmap and one using sklearn feature_importances.

When using the same data I get two difference values.

Here is the heatmap[image]

and heatmap code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

training_data = pd.read_csv(
    "/Users/aus10/NFL/Data/Betting_Data/CBB/Training_Data_Betting_CBB.csv")

df_model = training_data.copy()
df_model = df_model.dropna()
df_model = df_model.drop(['Money_Line', 'Money_Line_Percentage', 'Money_Line_Money', 'Money_Line_Move', 'Money_Line_Direction', "Spread", 'Spread_Percentage', 'Spread_Money', 'Spread_Move', 'Spread_Direction',
                          "Win", "Money_Line_Percentage", 'Cover'], axis=1)

X = df_model.loc[:, ['Total', 'Total_Move', 'Over_Percentage', 'Over_Money',
                     'Under_Percentage', 'Under_Money']]  # independent columns
y = df_model['Over_Under']  # target column

# get correlations of each features in dataset
corrmat = df_model.corr()
top_corr_features = corrmat.index
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
# plot heat map
g = sns.heatmap(
    df_model[top_corr_features].corr(), annot=True, cmap='hot')

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.yticks(rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

Here is the feature_importances bar graph
[image]

and the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance

training_data = pd.read_csv(
    "/Users/aus10/NFL/Data/Betting_Data/CBB/Training_Data_Betting_CBB.csv", index_col=False)

df_model = training_data.copy()
df_model = df_model.dropna()

X = df_model.loc[:, ['Total', 'Total_Move', 'Over_Percentage', 'Over_Money',
                     'Under_Percentage', 'Under_Money']]  # independent columns
y = df_model['Over_Under']  # target column

model = RandomForestClassifier(
    random_state=1, n_estimators=100, min_samples_split=100, max_depth=5, min_samples_leaf=2)

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)

skf.get_n_splits(X, y)

StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, random_state=None, shuffle=False)

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
# use inbuilt class feature_importances of tree based classifiers
print(model.feature_importances_)
# plot graph of feature importances for better visualization
feat_importances = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
perm_importance = permutation_importance(model, X_test, y_test)
feat_importances.nlargest(5).plot(kind='barh')

print(perm_importance)

plt.show()
```

I'm not sure which one is more accurate or if I'm using them in the correct way? Should I being using the heatmap to eliminate collinearity and the feature importances to actually selection my group of features?

Comment: The reason you are getting different values is because you are using different methods for finding which features has value in predicting your target. The first uses (Pearson) correlation while the second uses an impurity based method to find important features (see also the [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html)).

Comment: So when choosing features using different methods how do you decide which values are more accurate or can you use a combination of all the methods? @Oxbowerce